# Show my results bar chart in latex

Tags: diagrams, bar-chart, charts

I have a results of my research in the form of a bar chart created from excel work sheet. The image of my excel sheet and bar chart is given in the figure below;[image]
Please help me with code, I am new to latex and never draw these kind of bar charts earlier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search in forum. Many examples provided by experts can be found, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126577/31034

Comment: Open a terminal and type `texdoc pgfplots`. The PDF opening contains a lot of information. You will be able to do your above plot in very short time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt, where the data is read in via `pgfplotstableread`, since the data has two parallel axis label, a way to work around is to draw the plot twice and change the `xticklabel`on the second plot. Furthermore, this solution applies `shadows.blur` from `tikzlibrary` to have the shadow effects in order to mimic the shadow effect in the OP. the parameters `x/yshift` below can be changed to meet your need. As can be seen in the OP, the second labels were overlapped and this is improved by the `width=15cm` in the axis options, which can also be adjusted to meet one's need.

```
blur shadow={shadow yshift=0pt, shadow xshift=2pt}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc,shapes, positioning,shadows,shadows.blur,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{003366}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{pb}}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
items,section_1,section_2
max,centroid,82
max,bisector,82
max,mom,84
max,lom,84
max,som,71
sum,centroid,82
sum,bisector,82
sum,mom,80
sum,lom,79
sum,som,71
prob,centroid,82
prob,bisector,82
prob,mom,80
prob,lom,79
prob,som,71
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar=2pt, bar width=10pt,
    height=5cm, width=15cm,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    ymin=64, ymax=85,
    xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\datatable}{section_1}, 
x tick label style={rotate=90, xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.2cm, anchor=south,font=\small,align=center},
]
\addplot +[draw opacity=0, fill=darkblue,
blur shadow={shadow yshift=0pt, shadow xshift=2pt}]
table[x expr=\coordindex, y=section_2, ] {\datatable}; 
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ybar=2pt, bar width=10pt,
    height=5cm, width=15cm,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    ymin=64,  ymax=85,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{items}, 
    x tick label style={yshift=-2.2cm,anchor=south,font=\mystrut,align=center}, 
]
\addplot +[draw opacity=0, fill=darkblue,
blur shadow={shadow yshift=0pt, shadow xshift=2pt}]
table[x expr=\coordindex, y=section_2, ] {\datatable}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I draw this chart bar but the background only in bars is black, how can I set this ?

Comment: OK, you need to copy this file and put it into your current directory `tikzlibraryshadows.blur.code.tex - TeXdoc.net`. I used this keyword `shadow.blur, latex` search in the internet. Use pdflatex to compile.